# C# .net core Confluent.Kafka Avro Deserialization

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I have an avro class generated using.
avrogen -s customer-v1.avsc .

using Confluent.Kafka nuget package.
I am able to serialize my CustomerAvro and send to Kafka  Broker.

but I am having problem on deserializing because it is saying I don't have default deserializer being set.

[image]

can someone with expertise in this area be kind enough to give me a helping hand. 
Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest that you include the actual text in your question, not just an image? It makes it easier for people to read and answer, as well as helping others who might search for this same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to specify a deserializer via the builder class. e.g.: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroSpecific/Program.cs#L84

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the previous reply with the actual code, as the line number in the link provided is no longer correct

```
            using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig))
            using (var consumer =
                new ConsumerBuilder<string, User>(consumerConfig)
                    .SetKeyDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<string>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                    .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<User>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                    .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                    .Build())
```

The initial schemaRegistry is fundamental to enable the deserialiser to use the appropriate schema reference.

[Confluent.Kafka.Examples.AvroSpecific](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroSpecific/Program.cs)